# Same lib name in different subdirectories: conflics when calls `add_subdirectory` in parent level

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules, cmake-format

the simple folder structure is like

```
Root
    CMakeLists.txt
    SubA
        CMakeLists.txt
        some files to be built...
    SubB
        CMakeLists.txt
        some files to be built...
```

Assuming I have `add_library(SubDirLib fooX.cpp)` in both `SubA/CMakeLists.txt` and `SubB/CMakeLists.txt` where X is A and B respectively, how can I link two libraries `SubA/SubDirLib` and `SubB/SubDirLib` in `Root/CMakeLists.txt`? Note that it will be name conflicted if I call

```
add_subdirectory(SubA)
add_subdirectory(SubB)
```

in `Root/CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: You have no other choice than assign **different** names for both targets. **Why** do you want to have these names identical? (With knowing that we could give you more specific advises).

Comment: I think this is similar as what does `namespace` do in c++: developers do not need to worry about confliction beyond local scope since a call can always towards the full namespace path. One concret example is we have a lib called `utils` including many utility functions under said subfolder. Having `SubA/Utils` and `SubB/Utils` is quite common in the parent level, isn't it?

Comment: No, unlike to C++, targets names in CMake are **global** and should be **unique**. While the project is intended to be built as **standalone**, there is nothing bad in using "common" names (like "utils") for the targets. And many real projects (even widely-used ones) are designed to be built only as standalone. But if you plan to allow using the project with `add_subdirectory`, you need to make its targets  unique. E.g. by appending appropriate prefix for them: `LibA-utils`.